# notepad++ how to fold all current level

Tags: notepad++

So when I open my files in notepad++ I want all my function collapse, but not every little thing inside of those functions.  I'm using JavaScript.  Ctrl + Alt + F hides everything for 1 function, I want it to work for everything at the same level.  Is this possible or is there an addon for this?

Answer (score 0):

Alt + #, so if you want to hide the first level use 0, if you want to hide all at the second level use Alt + 1 ect.